# Inject bean map into Grails Service

Tags: spring, grails, grails-services

A spring bean can be injected in a Grails application using resources.groovy.   However, I would like to inject a map of beans. 
Key would be String, Value would an actual bean.  Idea is I am trying to do a strategy style pattern where there would be a look up to a map and a corresponding bean service invoked?

Is that possible - thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried `def mymap = [:]` then adding to it `mymap['key'] = ref('someBeanA')` then setting the property on your service in `Resources.groovy`? What didn't work about that? (Hint: it should work).

Comment: where those beans should be defined in the 1st place? some code would definitely help

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, but I wanted to inject a list of beans. This example works:

```
bean1(Bean1) {}

bean2(Bean2) {}

beansHolder (BeansHolder ) {
    beans = [bean1, bean2]
}
```

I think you can do the same for a map:

```
    beans = ['first': bean1, 'second': bean2]
```